# What is the meaning of "using" in this C# example?

Tags: c#

There are many questions about "using" in C# on StackOverflow, and the answers explain about namespaces ("using Npgsql;") and about defining a scope after which an object is disposed.  But this example, from a website showing how to connect to a PostGreSQL database, doesn't seem to fit either case:

```
using Npgsql;

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

var cs = "Host=localhost;Username=postgres;Password=postgres;Database=FoCH";

using var con = new NpgsqlConnection(cs);
con.Open();

var sql = "SELECT version()";

using var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, con);  // This is the line I don't understand

var version = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
Console.WriteLine($"PostgreSQL version: {version}");
```

Does that ensure that the object will be disposed when it reaches the end of the scope in which cmd is defined?  If not, what is it for?

Comment: that will just dipose the object at the end of the scope of the object

Comment: As suggested, the documentation explains exactly what's going on there. They basically added `using` declarations to avoid the indentation that a `using` statement requires, thus making the code more readable. You can often force an object to be disposed sooner  with a `using` statement but the difference is of no actual benefit so making code more readable is the more important consideration.

Answer (score 3):

If you examine the different types at the link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using), you'll see two possibilities, a *directive* and a *statement*.

---

The `using` ***directive*** basically "brings in" the namespace so that you can use it (and you state that you already understand this aspect so I won't cover it further):

```cs
using Plugh;
```

---

On the other hand, the `using` ***statement*** allows for use of a variable created from a namespace within a newly created scope, where the `IDisposable` variable is disposed of at the end of that scope:

```cs
using (Xyzzy xyzzy = Plugh.Twisty()) {
    // scoped area
}
```

---

There is a variation of the `using` *statement* called a `using` ***declaration***. This does not introduce a *new* scope, rather it creates the variable within the *current* scope.

The `IDisposable` variable is still disposed of when its scope ends, it's just the scope being used is slightly different:

```cs
using Xyzzy xyzzy = Plugh.Twisty();
```